# Postgres backup on top of existing database

Tags: postgresql

If I have a backup, I know I can typically do `psql dbname < infile`

but if I have an existing database and I want to write the backup on top, is there a simple way?

In other words,  I have a database that's currently live, and I have a backup.  The database crashed and now it only has a few rows, so I want to add my backup rows to the rows currently in the database.

Comment: what do you mean by "on top" ?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but `drop dbname; pg_restore -C -d dbname dbname.backup` would drop the database and recreate it from the backup. This assumes your backup was created using `pg_dump`

Comment: what if it's a .bak?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine but to clarify what I meant, I assumed you've backed up using a command like: `pg_dump -Fc dbname > dbname.bak`

Comment: That sounds like work. Do the tables have sequences? FK-constraints? Multiple schemas?